# bxslider images are not loading when used inside jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, bxslider

I am having issues with the images failing to load both in jquery ui and no ui tabs. Strangely enough, on opera, chrome and firefox, the images will load if I open the developer tools console and when I move the console up or down. The images totally fail in IE 11

Here is a live demo:

http://inetwebdesign.com/bxslider2/jquery-ui-tabs-accordion2.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
umb

Comment: No problems on IE11 over here

Comment: BxSlider and other plugins must be initialized after the tab is active for proper dimensions to be available.

Comment: Thanks isherwood. How do I do that? Regards, umbre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/bejFM/)** of **bxslider inside jquery-ui tabs**

JS code:

```
 $(function() {
     var slider2_initialized = false;
     var slider3_initialized = false;

     $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
         activate: function( event, ui ) {
            //console.log("ui = ");console.log(ui);
            var tab_id = $(ui.newPanel).attr('id');//alert(tab_id);

            if(tab_id == "tabs-2" && slider2_initialized == false)
            {    
                $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
                  auto:true,
                  mode: 'fade',
                  captions: true
                }); 
                //update initialization flag to true
                slider2_initialized = true;
            }
            else if(tab_id == "tabs-3" && slider3_initialized == false)
            {    
                $('.bxslider3').bxSlider({
                  auto:true,
                  mode: 'fade',
                  captions: true
                }); 
                //update initialization flag to true
                slider3_initialized = true;
            }
         }
     });

$('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
  auto:true,
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});     
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>
    <ul class="bxslider1">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
<p>
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <ul class="bxslider2">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
<p>
    <ul class="bxslider3">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. You rock dude!

Comment: Hi Rahul. Sometimes the images still fail to load. Debugger is not registering an error: http://inetwebdesign.com/bxslider2/jqueryui-tabs-accordion-bxslider2.html  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but also the bxslider would break on my media queries jump points. My solution in the end was to use Super Simple Slider inside the tabs and to use bxslider for everything else. I hope this helps.